# Best way to transfer data from Node to webGL running in browser?

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js, electron, node.js-addon

I’m creating a 3D application which uses a node addon written in C++ to generate 3D objects (vertices, normals, indices etc) which I need to pass down to my webGL window (I’m using Three.js).  My application is wrapped up in Electron.

What is the most efficient way to transmit my large data arrays (My 3D objects contain many polygons) from C++ (Node addon) to the renderer front end? Ideally I would love it if I could allocate some heap memory in C++ and have it accessible from the renderer thread in electron to create the Three.Js objects. Is that even possible?

Right now I’m allocating buffers in C++, passing them down to Node’s (main thread) via v8, and then using Electron's MainWindow.webContents to send this data to the render thread which can then create my Three.js objects for rendering in webGL. This seems inefficient so I hope there is a better way.

The alternatives that I was considering is having the C++ code create a file, and then have the front end read the file.

Comment: Enabling node.js integration in renderer process is not an option? That'll allow accessing node addon directly in renderer process.

Comment: How do you do that?

Comment: Electron's browserwindow enables node integration by default unless you disabled it when you create it.

Comment: We used a websocket, similar to your application. A C++ library prepares the buffers, sends them to a websocket, where the renderer process receives it and moves the data into a webGL buffer. Also seems pretty inificent, but we initially needed to send data fairly slowly, so not a problem so far. 
I hope it might be possible to pass the webGL context to C++ through a native module loaded from the renderer.